# Handlebars if/else not working even if the statement is true

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Why can't Handlebars check if the Custom Claims Admin is true it automatically goes to the else statement even though the statement for the custom claims is true. Photo of the CustomClaims attached.
[image: The admin:true is under metadata thats why i linked it as metadata.customClaims.admin]

```
                  {{#each listusersarray}}
              <tr>
                   <td>{{email}}</td>
                   <td>{{metadata.lastSignInTime}}</td>

              <td>{{#if metadata.customClaims.admin}}Admin{{else}}User{{/if}}</td>

             <td>
              {{!-- <input type="hidden" value="{{uid}}" id="user-uid"> --}}
              {{#if disabled}}
              <button class="btn btn-success " type="button" onclick="enableaccountFunction('{{uid}}')">Enable Account</button>
              {{else}}
              <button class="btn btn-danger " type="button" onclick="disableaccountFunction('{{uid}}')">Disable Account</button>
              {{/if }}
              <input type="hidden" value="{{email}}" id="admin-email">
              <button class="btn btn-primary " onclick="makeadminFunction('{{uid}}')">Make Admin</button>
            </td>



              </tr>
            {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad customClaims is not under metadata thats why it is undefined its only customClaims.admin